# Django - Deduplicate based on multiple attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model representing an answer (can be correct or incorrect) to a question. A user might give multiple incorrect and multiple correct answers.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
   
   match_event_id = models.UUIDField(
      primary_key=True,
      default=uuid.uuid4
      )
   user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   test_session = models.ForeignKey(TestSession, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   # The actual text answer provided by the user
   event_text = models.TextField(default="")
   # Indicate if the answer is correct or not
   match_success = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   # Client name
   client = models.TextField(default="Unknown")
```

I'd like to create a query which counts the number of correctly answere questions but not the number of correct answers.

Currently my basic query looks like this:

```
count_success = Answer.objects.filter(user_profile=self.user_profile_id, match_success=True).count()
```

This gives me the number of all correct answers but since there might be multiple correct answers per question this is not what I want.

How can I do some kind of deduplication based on user_profile, test_session, question and match_success? So whenever there is one correct answer by the user to one question in a test session I'd like to add 1 to the count.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `annotate` to group by the questions with their correct or false answers. Your query might be look like that. You can test it, may be it give you desired result.

```
count_success = Answer.objects.filter(user_profile=self.user_profile_id, match_success=True).count().values('question', 'user_profile', 'test_session').annotate(Count('match_success'))
```

Comment: Hi. thank you. After some tinkering around I came up with this query.               
count_success = Answer.objects.filter(user_profile=self.user_profile_id, match_success=True).values("question", "test_session").distinct().count() which seems to work well.